# Converting Foxpro to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-foxpro

I wasn't sure what to title this post, if you can think of a better title, feel free to edit my post.

I have some visual foxpro that looks like this:

```
* Get the vendor code for case management hours
Select op_value ;
    FROM dbfs\am_opts ;
    WHERE op_code = "CMGT_VENDOR" ;
    INTO CURSOR cmgt_vndr
lcCMGTVendor = padr(cmgt_vndr.op_value, 4)



* Determine if we need to include CMGT hours
llIncludeCMGT = .f.

Select sub_code ;
    FROM tempsrv ;
    WHERE Is_It_Case_Service(sub_code) ;
    AND selected ;
    INTO CURSOR c_dummy1
*
If _tally
 > 0 or pcService = "ALL"
    llIncludeCMGT = .t.
Endif
*
If m.llIncludeCMGT
    *   Pick only certain Vendors?
    If m.pcVendor=="ALL"
        *   No, then leave the CMGT flag as DO Include.
    Else
        *   Yes, only get CMGT if the "Default CMGT Vendor"
        *   is one of the selected vendors.
        Select 'TempVnd'
        Locate FOR provkey=m.lcCMGTVendor .AND. Selected
        m.llIncludeCMGT = FOUND()
        *
        *
    Endif
    *
Endif
*
*
* Merge in CMGT hours if necessary
If llIncludeCMGT
    Wait WINDOW NOWAIT ;
        'Gathering Case-Management entries'
    *
    * 10/25/2001 JDB Take into account f_rpt.sub_code
    *
    Select 0

    Use 'dbfs\f_Rpt' AGAIN ALIAS 'SQL_F_Rpt' NOUPDATE
    *
    *   Build basic WHERE-clause, and name basic tables.
    m.SQL_FROM = "SQL_F_Rpt"
    m.SQL_WHERE = "SQL_F_Rpt.End_Dt BETWEEN m.pdBegin_Date AND m.pdEnd_Date" ;
        + " AND !(IS_IT_WAIVER(SQL_F_Rpt.Payor, .F.))"
    *
    *   Do they only want certain Fund-Sources?
    If m.pcPayor=="ALL"
        *   No, ignore the Payor-field
    Else
        *   Yes, only get matching/selected payors.
        m.SQL_FROM = m.SQL_FROM + ", TempPay"
        m.SQL_WHERE = m.SQL_WHERE ;
            + " AND SQL_F_Rpt.Payor=TempPay.Payor_CD" ;
            + " AND TempPay.Selected"
        *
    Endif
    *

    *   Pick only certain Service-Codes?
    If m.pcService=="ALL"
        *   No, ignore the SubCode-field
    Else
        *   Yes, only get matching/selected Services.
        m.SQL_FROM = m.SQL_FROM + ", TempSrv"
        m.SQL_WHERE = m.SQL_WHERE ;
            + " AND IIF(EMPTY(SQL_F_Rpt.Sub_Code), 'CMGT', SQL_F_Rpt.Sub_Code)=TempSrv.Sub_Code" ;
            + " AND TempSrv.Selected"
        *
    Endif
    *
    *







    Select * from pass2 union all ;
        select lcCMGTVendor as provkey, ;
        iif(empty(SQL_F_Rpt.sub_code), "CMGT", SQL_F_Rpt.sub_code) as sub_code, ;
        SQL_F_Rpt.keyfld, ;
        00000.00 as tot_auth, ;
        (SQL_F_Rpt.unit * SQL_F_Rpt.cost) as tot_deliv, ;
        SQL_F_Rpt.start_dt as plandt ;
        from &SQL_FROM ;
        where &SQL_WHERE ;
        into cursor pass3
```

I don't how the `lcCMGTVendor` is getting incorporated into the final foxpro query. It's not in the `SQL_WHERE` clause anywhere. It is not referenced anywhere else in the code, just this part.

Can someone help me figure out what I am missing in order to figure out how it is in the Foxpro query at the bottom?

In my current understanding, we are taking whatever the provkey value and literally applying it to every row, which seems wrong.

Comment: About line 6 is  lcCMGTVendor = padr(cmgt_vndr.op_value, 4)

Comment: so that value gets applied to every single record at the bottom?

Comment: Yes. Are you a beginner to FoxPro? You should start with something simpler.

Comment: I am a beginner to foxpro. I am translating foxpro into T-SQL for a task I am assigned to. 

Thanks

Comment: IMHO it is not an easy task translating Foxpro code to T-SQL even for the seasoned foxpro and MS SQL Server developers. It would make more sense if you wanted to convert it to another language like C#, Go, Python ... but trying to convert to T-SQL, pgSQL ... doesn't make sense.

Comment: Foxpro is used to query data out of a database and I need to replicate the same results in T-SQL. Once I can confirm that my match is accurate against one database, I need to see if it matches in another database. If it doesn't match, I've messed up my SQL on that side.

Comment: I am trying to tell you, FoxPro besides doing SQL have xBase and general purpose OOP language  specifics. For example, if you encounter a line like: "o = CreateObject('empty')", how would you convert it to T-SQL?

Comment: I get that it has OOP language specifics, I was simply explaining what I was trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186948/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-lunchbox).

Answer (score 1):

OK, you want to convert parts of it, then the "part" you are asking to, in practice correspond to:

Foxpro code:

```
* Get the vendor code for case management hours
Select op_value ;
    FROM dbfs\am_opts ;
    WHERE op_code = "CMGT_VENDOR" ;
    INTO CURSOR cmgt_vndr
lcCMGTVendor = padr(cmgt_vndr.op_value, 4)
```

T-SQL:

```
declare @lcCMGTVendor char(20+4); -- if op_value size is char(20)
Select top(1) @lcCMGTVendor = op_value 
        FROM am_opts
        WHERE op_code = 'CMGT_VENDOR';
```

IMHO padr() was not something necessary even in foxpro code. Above code anyway use char(20+4) instead of varchar() - foxpro fields have trailing spaces.

Comment: The very bottom query is what I was trying to produce in SQL. I was able to replicate everything except for that one column I mentioned earlier. I thought there was some sort of join or something I was missing that adds that value, but after reading your comments, I think I got it.